# Runtime error "424: Object Required"

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I am having difficulties with this code.  I am trying to make it so that based on the value of cell `D25` the value of `F25` will change.  I made the code in VBA (don’t know if this is actually the best way) and it is giving me a `424 runtime error: Object Required`.  Could someone please point me in the right direction?

```
Sub Storage_vesel_Controle()

   Sheets("NSR Form").Select

   If Range("D25") = "1" Then Range("F25").Select.Value = "0"

   If Range("D25") = "2" Then Range("F25").Select.Value = ".95"

   If Range("D25") = "3" Then Range("F25").Select.Paste = ".98"

End Sub
```

Also, what do I need to add to make the code "always running"... in loop I think?

Comment: Change `Range("F25").Select.Value = "0"` tp `Range("F25").Value = "0"`

Comment: ...and rather remove quotation marks after `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to my comment above, I wasn't planning on posting an answer but saw few things which I think I will bring to your notice and comments wouldn't accommodate so much of text.

I would recommend not using `.Select` to select the sheet but work with the sheet directly (See Below code) You might also want to see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select/10718179#10718179)

```
Sub Storage_vesel_Controle()
    With Sheets("NSR Form")
        Select Case .Range("D25").Value
           Case 1: .Range("F25").Value = 0
           Case 2: .Range("F25").Value = 0.95
           Case 3: .Range("F25").Value = 0.98
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT**:

Regarding your edit. You can use the `Worksheet_Change` Event to ensure that the values of F25 gets automatically updated or if you want a non VBA solution then simply use a Formula in `F25`

If you are interested in `Worksheet_Change` then see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640). Else a simple formula like this in `F25` will suffice your needs :)

```
=IF(D25=1,0,IF(D25=2,0.95,IF(D25=3, 0.98,"")))
```

Comment: Worksheet_Change?  Is that a individual set of cod eyou write?

Comment: @DavidVanderVieren: Refresh the page :) You will see the latest edits.

Answer (score 1):

Clean it up a little bit. Using a `Select Case` statement will be easier to work with than mutliple If/Then statements.

```
Sub Storage_vesel_Controle()
    With Sheets("NSR Form")
        .Activate  '<this line is not actually necessary unless you want to be on the sheet.
        Select Case .Range("D25").Value
            Case 1
                .Range("F25").Value = 0
            Case 2
                .Range("F25").Value = 0.95
            Case 3
                .Range("F25").Paste = 0.98
            Case Else
                'do nothing, or, modify as needed
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 on Select Case :) I was few seconds late